# Clang AST - isNullPointerConstant()

Tags: clang, abstract-syntax-tree, llvm-clang, clang-static-analyzer

I'm trying to check if input arguments to a CallExpr is null/nil in Objective C using Clang's AST

I saw that there is a method isNullPointerConstant() that seems like it will do what I want http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1Expr.html#ab56d6fd074c831a3e63b45f4f226b35a

However, I'm not really sure how to invoke this method. Specifically, what is NullPointerConstantValueDependence that it is taking in and what is NullPointerConstantKind of the return?

What I need to do is just evaluate whether an argument is null or not, a boolean return value would work fine. Is there any other way that I should be looking at?

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me in the end

```
Expr::NullPointerConstantKind kind = expr->isNullPointerConstant(*Context, Expr::NullPointerConstantValueDependence());
```

If kind is > 0, means there are some form of null pointer and one can retrieve it to see the cause of it.